# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable python. Im trying to combine every .mp4 file into one video

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to combine every .mp4 file in a certin folder into one a single .mp4 file

```
video_files = glob.glob("*.mp4")
print(video_files)


final = concatenate_videoclips[video_files]
final.write_videofile("new.mp4", codec="libx264")
```

The error I get is

```
final = concatenate_videoclips[video_files];
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

if anyone could explain what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

First, the subscriptable part meant that you should use `(` and `)` instead of `[` and `]`. Second, you cannot simply put the names of the files into the function, you need to first convert them into `VideoFileClip`:

```
# from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip,concatenate_videoclips
# import glob

video_files = glob.glob("*.mp4")

clips = []

for clip in video_files: # For each mp4 file name
    clips.append(VideoFileClip(clip)) # Store them as a VideoFileClip and add to the clips list


final = concatenate_videoclips(clips) # Concatenate the VideoFileClips
final.write_videofile("new.mp4", codec="libx264")
```